# How to make Google Sheet arrayformula work with date functions

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a column of dates with the format `"yyyy-mm-dd"`. And I want to do summary statistics by month -- using native formulas.

When I put `arrayformula` around `month(...)>month(...)`, I get the error

> Result was not expanded automatically, please insert more rows (1).

Why is that? And how do I get around that?

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WFVgkEsyjo9KkeMxBx4jsCyIM-WYunOMqdAL3qqHaVc/edit#gid=1505224999). Formula in `B4`.

```
=arrayformula(month(B4:B)>month(B3:B))
```

Note: I don't know the number of rows ahead of time -- it is expected to update from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, erase your formula, it is trying to automatically expand the sheet and the sheet already has over 50,000 rows.

Next delete 48,000 rows or so.

Next put this formula in cell B4:

```
=arrayformula(month(B4:B)>month(arrayconstrain(B3:B,rows(B4:B),1)))
```

That will prevent the formula from auto-expanding the sheet.

That should work, though I think you're going to realize you don't like what happens when the year changes.  I believe this to be an [xyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Works with `array_constrain` (and `<>`).

Answer (score 0):

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(B4:B),,month(B5:B)>month(B4:B)))
```

works.

It seems it is always better to include an `isblank()` wrap to avoid indefinite expansion of the sheet.

Comment: That doesn't work because of the ISBLANK(). It works because you're putting something in row 4 that is comparing against row 5 and down.  In the first example you were putting something row 4 that was comparing against row 3 and down.  That will not work, even with an ISBLANK() wrap.

Comment: @MattKing: I see. I'll take another look. Thanks for the explanation!